# How to assign a variable to two columns from a text file in python

Tags: python, linear-regression, txt

I have been given a text file with approximately 100 different rows and I am curious how I can assign each of the two columns with a variable so I can easily be able to do a linear regression with them. Any

```
file = open("linear.txt")
m = sum((x(i) - mean(x)) * (y(i) - mean(y))) / sum((x(i) - mean(x))**2)
c = mean(y) - x* mean(x)
def mean(values):
    return sum(values) / float(len(values))
variance = sum((x - mean(x))**2)


def variance(values, mean):
    return sum([(x-mean)**2 for x in values])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go through the lines of the your file then split your row to two different variables. like:

```
with open ("your_file_path","r") as f:
    for line in f:
        var1,var2 = line.split(" ") # I used a space, but you can select what ever sperator you have in your file
```